# how to log pipelines in Java project reactor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I have started a new project that uses java reactor and spring webFLux. Recently I had to debug a production bug and It was a nightmare since they do not log anything. So, reading I found two ways to start adding logs to pipelines. One by using .log() and another one by using onErrorResume, doOnSubscribe, doOnSuccess. Do you know which one should I use? Are better ways to log pipelines?

```
    return repositoryName.findById(event.eventId())
        .filter(event -> event.completedDate() == null)
        .filterWhen(event ->
            externalService.getEventSummary(event.getUser().userId())
        .doOnNext(event -> log.info("Event found {} and should be marked as found", event.id()))
```

Comment: You can check https://spring.io/blog/2019/04/16/flight-of-the-flux-2-debugging-caveats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend the Reactor doc to check what each method does https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/

***doOnNext***, ***doOnError***, ***doOnSuccess*** are highly used to execute blocking operations without side effects on the current stream. If you received a Square object on your ***doOnNext*** and ***doOnError***, this method would return precisely the received Square object (even if you changed its properties)

***doOnNext*** to execute after the previous sequence finishes **try-catch**

***doOnError*** the subsequent execution if an exception was thrown (and there's no other exception handler on stream)

***doOnSuccess*** is similar to a finally block from **try-catch**

***onErrorResume*** is most used to handle exceptions if needed, similar to catch(Exception e), but it will return a new object

As you can see, it's okay to have logs on ***flatMap***, ***map***, ***doOnNext***, ***doOnError***, or ***onErrorResume***. The correct one to use will vary on what you need. If logging is the only thing you need, I recommend ***doOnNext***, ***doOnError***, or ***doOnFinally***.

As said before, please refer to the docs too to check what each method stands for